# Script is not getting deployed on local hardhat network due to some type error

Tags: hardhat-deploy

```
// imports
const { ethers, run, network } = require("hardhat")

// async main
async function main() {
  const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")
  console.log("Deploying contract...")
  const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy
  await simpleStorage.deployed
  console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${simpleStorage.address}`)
  // what happens when we deploy to our hardhat network?
  if (network.config.chainId === 5 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    console.log("Waiting for block confirmations...")
    await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6)
    await verify(simpleStorage.address, [])
  }

  const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
  console.log(`Current Value is: ${currentValue}`)

  // Update the current value
  const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store(7)
  await transactionResponse.wait(1)
  const updatedValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve()
  console.log(`Updated Value is: ${updatedValue}`)
}

// async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
const verify = async (contractAddress, args) => {
  console.log("Verifying contract...")
  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      constructorArguments: args,
    })
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already Verified!")
    } else {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}

// main
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

This is the deploy script.

```
{
  "name": "hardhat-simple-storage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.7",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.4.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^8.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
    "ethers": "^5.5.3",
    "hardhat": "^2.8.3",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.1.3",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.7.18",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```

This is hardhat config file

When i am running the following command
`yarn hardhat run scripts/deploy.js`
it is giving the mentioned error

```
Deploying contract...
Deployed contract to: undefined
TypeError: simpleStorage.retrieve is not a function
    at main (/root/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage/scripts/deploy.js:18:44)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: I must've missed the `simpleStorage.retrieve` error. Maybe share the contract code of retrieve function, since that's where the problem is originating.

Comment: ```function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
    return favoriteNumber;
  }```

Answer (score 0):

Its solved just needed to degrade the ethers version.
ran this command in terminal:
`yarn add --dev ethers@^5.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the ethers package you have if it's beyond version 5, then install version 5.7.3 preferably